# why does wordpress ignore the post args?

Tags: posts, categories, loop

I dont get it. Straight outa the Codex,

```
 <?php
// my code

    $cat = get_the_category(); 
    $catName = $category[0]->cat_name;

//straight outa the codex

  // The Query
  query_posts( array ( 'category' => $catName, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

  // The Loop
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </li>

  <?php endwhile;

  // Reset Query
  wp_reset_query();

  ?>
```

The results are every post in the entire blog, not every post in the category $catName. Whats up with that?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain what you're trying to do, in context. Are you trying to modify the main loop query, or add a secondary query loop?

Answer (score 3):

[There is no `category` argument:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

- **cat** (*int*) - use category id.
- **category_name** (*string*) - use category slug (NOT name).
- **category__and** (*array*) - use category id.
- **category__in** (*array*) - use category id.
- **category__not_in** (*array*) - use category id.

You want to be using the `category_name` argument-- note that it takes the *slug* not the *name*--, though I'd recommend using the `ID`.

And...

[Please don't use `query_posts`.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/21376)